# how to read all line except the first line?

Tags: arduino-uno

is there a way to read only 2nd up to the last line except for the first line?

here's my sample code

```
File myFile;
char cr;
void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");



  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());



    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

skip first line

```
bool firstLine = true;
while (myFile.available()) {
  int c = myFile.read();
  if (firstLine) {
    if (c == '\n') {
      firstLine = false;
    }
  } else {
    Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do reads for the first line, ignore them and start the while thus:

```
while (myFile.available() && (myFile.read() != '\n') {}; // Empty while body
while (myFile.available()) {
  Serial.write(myFile.read());
}
```

Comment: @michael
how do i block/skip the first line and read the 2nd line up to the last line?

Comment: By reading the first line and don't use it as in the code above.

Comment: myFile.read(); reads only one byte/char

Comment: @Juraj Thanks and improved my answer accordingly

Comment: and what for is the endOfLineFound test in second while?

Comment: @Juraj It's indeed not needed, so it can be removed without any functional change. Thanks again. Also I removed the variable for the while condition.